# Using TcxPopUpEdit

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have tried using a cxGrid and TcxPopEdit to create a checkedComboBox, and I implemented to check each checkbox in the list and show the checked value in PopupEdit.

For extending it a bit, I had added a PopupMenu for the GridView.

Now , there are two buttons say Select all , Clear all on popupmenu, When i rightclick the gridview and say selectall it should check all the checkboxes and when i say clear all it should uncheck all checkboxes.

Can anyone please suggest me some idea for achieving this?
By the way we are using Dev Express 5.15(Express QuantumGrid v5.15 etc..) with Borland Delphi 6 as Development IDE.

I am attaching a screenshot of how my app looks.
[image: App ScreenShot]
Here is the Source which i implemented for doing this Get the Sample Project from DropBox.
[SampleProject](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsvj73kxy28ieup/CxPopupEdit_Sample_CDS.zip?dl=0)

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We are happy to answer specific questions you may have regarding *your implementation*. Why don't you do it yourself, what is the actual problem? Also, you have been a member long enough to know that all details of a question MUST be included in the question itself. External links may stop working, thus rendering your question worthless for future readers.

Comment: I just wanted some suggestions of how to proceed with my requirement. I am trying on the same.

Comment: I am not downloading your DropBox code, but ... The easiest way to do this is simply to traverse the dataset (bracketed between calls to Disable- and EnableControls), setting or clearing the field which populates the checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will set or clear the checkboxes associated with a field called 'Marked' in the dataset connected to your grid's datasource.  If that is not what you are trying to do, you need to be more specific in your q.

```
procedure TForm1.ProcessCheckboxes(SetCB : Boolean);
var
  ADataSet : TDataSet;
  BM : TBookmark;
  Field : TField;
begin
  ADataSet := DataSource1.DataSet;
  Field := ADataSet.FieldByName('Marked')
  BM := ADataSet.GetBookmark;  //  Place a bookmark on the dataset so that the
  //  same row stays current
  try
    ADataSet.DisableControls;  //  temporarily prevent the grid from being updated on-screen
    ADataSet.First;
    while not ADataSet.Eof do begin
      ADataSet.Edit;
      if SetCB then
        Field.Value := True
      else
        Field.Value := False;
      ADataSet.Post;
      ADataSet.Next;
    end;
  finally
    ADataSet.GoToBookMark(BM);  //  go back to the row where we placed the bookmark
    ADataSet.FreeBookMark(BM);
    ADataSet.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on your project code, i write some code that are very close to @MartynA answer, but base on your codes.I did not test them but the main logic for your needs is in both answer. for do this you have to change data not change component property directly.

```
procedure TfrmCXPopUpEdit.CheckAll1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  ADataSet : TDataSet;
  bm : TBookmark;
begin
    bm := CDS_LookUp.GetBookmark;
    CDS_LookUp.DisableControls;
    CDS_LookUp.first;
    while  not CDS_LookUp.eof do
    begin
        CDS_LookUp.edit;
        CDS_LookUpDBFLAG.AsBoolean := true;
        CDS_LookUp.post;
        CDS_LookUp.next;
    end;
    CDS_LookUp.GoToBookMark(bm); 
    CDS_LookUp.FreeBookMark(bm);
    CDS_LookUp.EnableControls;
end;

procedure TfrmCXPopUpEdit.ClearAll1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  ADataSet : TDataSet;
  bm : TBookmark;
begin
    bm := CDS_LookUp.GetBookmark;
    CDS_LookUp.DisableControls;
    CDS_LookUp.first;
    while  not CDS_LookUp.eof do
    begin
        CDS_LookUp.edit;
        CDS_LookUpDBFLAG.AsBoolean := false;
        CDS_LookUp.post;
        CDS_LookUp.next;
    end;
    CDS_LookUp.GoToBookMark(bm);  
    CDS_LookUp.FreeBookMark(bm);
    CDS_LookUp.EnableControls;
end;
```